# How to refresh a cube in SSAS, after making change to database

Tags: ssas

I made change to database, only changed datatypes from int to money.. But I can't make it appear in my cube, it is still unchanged. But if I create new cube, it is OK. But I don't want to create new cubes every time I change something in database...

Some know how do refresh the cube? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to first refresh your Data Source View, then edit wherever you are using that column in cubes or dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

if you right click on your project containing your cube and then select "Process", cube will be processed and the data in the cube will be updated with the data on database .